# Remove specific emails from sendmail mqueue

Tags: linux, logs, email, sendmail, mqueue

How do I remove emails from `mqueue` based on destination address. Needing to remove deferred messages going to "4239038497@txt.att.net"

Due to an endless loop (that has been found and corrected) I have a huge amount of emails deferred or qued for retry in `var/spool/mqueue`. Need to clear these out ASAP as the bounceback messages are filling up my var/log folder space by 1G every 20min.

There is legit email also in the que so can't just empty `var/spool/mqueue`. How do I filter to just the results I am looking for? And, do I need to stop sendmail first?

Results from **df -h** in `mqueue` showing `/dev/sda2` filesystem 100% used due to `var/log`

```
root@tsunami12:/var/log# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G  650M  5.7G  11% /run
/dev/sda2        28G   28G    0G 100% /
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda4       2.1T  986G 1013G  50% /home
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1002
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1003
```

Results from ls -lh in `mqueue`

```
root@tsunami12:/var/spool/mqueue# 
ls -lh

-rw-r----- 1 smmta smmsp    0 Mar 17  2020 df02H2TsFs012156
-rw-r----- 1 root  smmsp 2.8K Apr 14 10:17 df33EDseEV018975
-rw-r----- 1 root  smmsp 3.6K Apr 14 10:12 df33EECwjo001842
-rw-r----- 1 root  smmsp 2.3K Apr 14 10:43 df33EEhHEt023903
-rw-r----- 1 root  smmsp 2.3K Apr 14 10:45 df33EEj5ai025020
```

Results from **mailq** command

```
33J38Htu005703     3623 Tue Apr 18 23:08 <answerserv@callactionair.com>
                  (Deferred)
                                          <4239038497@txt.att.net>
                                          <4238837942@vtext.com>
                                          <4236679922@vtext.com>
                                          <4236679911@vtext.com>
                                          <4233947202@vtext.com>
33J382mj005213     3623 Tue Apr 18 23:08 <answerserv@callactionair.com>
                 (Deferred)
                                         <4239038497@txt.att.net>
                                         <4238837942@vtext.com>
                                         <4236679922@vtext.com>
                                         <4236679911@vtext.com>
                                         <4233947202@vtext.com>
```

Results from root@tsunami12:/var/log# **tail mail.log** command

```
Apr 19 15:54:56 tsunami12 sm-mta[22495]: 33INJGL5000565: to=<4233947202@vtext.com>,<4236679911@vtext.com>,<4236679922@vtext.com>,<4238837942@vtext.com>, delay=20:35:40, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=10924132, relay=smtpin01.vzw.a.cloudfilter.net., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by smtpin01.vzw.a.cloudfilter.net.
Apr 19 15:54:56 tsunami12 sm-mta[15318]: 33J0R2EH028306: to=<4236455765@txt.att.net>,<4239038497@txt.att.net>, delay=19:27:53, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=10655014, relay=att-e2xms-west.mx.a.cloudfilter.net., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by att-e2xms-west.mx.a.cloudfilter.net.
Apr 19 15:54:56 tsunami12 sm-mta[15318]: 33J0R2EH028306: to=<4237628227@pm.sprint.com>, delay=19:27:53, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=10655014, relay=tmo-east.mx.a.cloudfilter.net., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by tmo-east.mx.a.cloudfilter.net.
Apr 19 15:54:56 tsunami12 sm-mta[15318]: 33J0R2EH028306: to=<4233947202@vtext.com>,<4236679911@vtext.com>,<4236679922@vtext.com>,<4238837942@vtext.com>, delay=19:27:53, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=10655014, relay=smtpin01.vzw.a.cloudfilter.net., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by smtpin01.vzw.a.cloudfilter.net.
```

Comment: _How do I filter to just the results I am looking for?_ As long as we don't know what results you are looking for, nobody can help you.

Comment: @stoney added more detail thank you

Answer (score 0):

From memory I recall there are `df*` files and corresponding `qf*` files but since I don't run `sendmail` here I can't guarantee that. You should find that one acceptable approach is to remove files from `/var/spool/mqueue` that contain the text `4239038497@txt.att.net`. Not perfect but very close.

```
cd /var/spool/mqueue
mkdir /var/spool/mq.rm
mv $(grep -l '4239038497@txt.att.net' *) ../mq.rm
```

You should now have a much shortened mail queue and the messages pending deletion in the directory `/var/spool/mq.rm`.

**As always test thoroughly before applying to your live environment**